# How to do double-indirection with jq variables?

Tags: variables, jq

How to construct a name of a variable from data and access that variable?

For example it should somehow give the content of the alpha-file:

```
jq '$.var"-file"' --slurpfile alpha-file <(echo 0) --slurpfile beta-file <(echo 1) <<<'{"var": "alpha"}'
```

It should output:

```
[
  0
]
```

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question. Could you please add an example, a [mre] ?

Comment: Added expected output.

Comment: What is `alpha-file`, `beta-file` and why do you use two process substitutions, and one here-string?

Comment: Used bash syntax to shorten the example. The here-string represents a data file that has information about whether to choose `alpha-file` or `beta-file`. If it's alpha then `alpha-file` is used, if beta then `beta-file` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named arguments are also available to the jq program as `$ARGS.named`.

So there is a dictionary to extract variables by a string name from:

```
jq '$ARGS.named["\(.var)-file"]' --slurpfile alpha-file <(echo 0) --slurpfile beta-file <(echo 1) <<<'{"var": "alpha"}'
```

outputs

```
[
  0
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getpath` like this:

```
jq --slurpfile alphaFile <(echo 0) --slurpfile betaFile <(echo 1) '
   .var as $ab | {alpha: $alphaFile, beta: $betaFile} | getpath([$ab])' <<< '{"var": "alpha"}'
```

Better yet:

```
jq --slurpfile alpha <(echo 0) --slurpfile beta <(echo 1) '
   .var as $ab | {$alpha, $beta} | getpath([$ab])' <<< '{"var": "alpha"}'
```